# How do I set up username/password authentication with Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm just trying out the new [Vault UI](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/vault-oss-ui-introduction). I'd like to be able to log in with a username and password. How do I create a new user from the command line so I can log in with a username and password?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a new user like so:

```
vault write auth/userpass/users/<username> policies=default password=<passwd>
```

You have to be authenticated as root (or another user with sufficient permissions) and have enabled the `userpass` auth method.